# PHP - How to show the list of products being sold depending on the user's location?

Tags: php, location

I am building a bookstore website and I am looking for ways I can show the books beings sold depending on the city (or zip code) that the user is. Let's say I live in Dallas and the only books that I am able to see are the ones that are being sold in the same city or in a close area.

Comment: Using a db query to select the right products sound like a good idea. If you want more spesific help you should try to implement this and post some code if you're having problems :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using maxminds geoip databases [1]. They have a free version. With it you can get the zipcode of a user by his ip address. Then you can easily query which books are sold in his area and show them to the user.
[1] https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-services-and-databases